# Dynamically setting PasswordStrengthRegularExpression

Tags: asp.net, passwords

Some, but not all, of my clients are complaining that requiring a non-alphanumeric character in the account password is too complicated for their clients, so I was looking into PasswordStrengthRegularExpression.

Is there a way to set PasswordStrengthRegularExpression dynamically, so I can ease the requirements for certain clients, but not others?

Answer (score 0):

You can set this when you configure membership in your `.config` file, as described in the MSDN documentation for [`PasswordStrengthRegularExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.passwordstrengthregularexpression.aspx):

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider"
  userIsOnlineTimeWindow = "20>
  <providers>
    <add
      name="SqlProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
      connectionStringName="SqlServices"
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
      passwordStrengthRegularExpression=" @\"(?=.{6,})(?=(.*\d){1,})(?=(.*\W){1,})"
      />
   </providers>
</membership>
```

Have a different configuration for the clients that need a different requirement to the default.